# Serial communIcation from OS X app to Arduino Mega

Tags: serial, communication

I am new to stack overflow. I have a question regarding using the USB serial communication sending data from an OS X app to the Arduino Mega 2560.

What happens is, when I have the Arduino running with the Serial monitor open, then I run the OS X app to send data, the Arduino does receive the data for a few seconds, then it stops.

This is the simplified Object-C code on the Mac side:

```
-(IBAction)sendData:(id)sender{
    NSString *toSend=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"echo %f > /dev/tty.usbmodem1a1341" ,vector.x];
    //vector is the continuous data generated by the Mac
    const char *toCSend =[toSend UTF8String];
    //converting to c string
    printf("%s", toCSend);
    popen(toCSend, "r");
}
```

This is the code on the Arduino side:

```
// Read Serial input:
void setup() {
  // Open Serial commurial1.beginnications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    // wait for Serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Read Serial input:
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int inChar = Serial.read();
    if (inChar != '\n') {
      inString += (char)inChar;
      Serial.read();
    } else {
      // if you get a newline, print the string,
      // then the string's value as a float:
      Serial.println(inString.toFloat(), 6);
      // clear the string for new input:
      inString = "";
    }//end of if else
  }//end of while (Serial.available() > 0)
}
```

I am not sure what the problem, could it be the OS X app send out too much data to quickly? Or could it be the Arduino serial buffer is overflowed?

I really don't know much about serial communication so I don't know what I am missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should close the serial monitor before you run your custom OSX program.  Just as it auto closes when you upload, only one program should (ordinarily) be using the port at a time.  You may want to build simple output monitoring to the screen/stdout into your custom program.

Comment: Like Chris said, opening a serial connection will reset the Arduino, so you probably should add some delay in your OBJC code. Secondly you haven't set a baudrate. Try [something like this](http://superuser.com/a/846255)

Comment: Actually, the reset or not is configurable with stty on linux/OSX, and may (perhaps?) not occur if the port is already open by someone else.  But it is indeed one of the several concerns - having the serial monitor grab responses before your program can being another.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is here:

```C++
  // Read Serial input:
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int inChar = Serial.read();

    if (inChar != '\n') {
      inString += (char)inChar;
      Serial.read();
    }
```

Your Serial.available() call guarantees that you have **one** byte of serial input, but you are attempting to read two of them if the first one is not a newline. This is not valid.

[How to process incoming serial data without blocking](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial)